# Calling a dictionary outside the class in main() block in python

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I have two python scripts as below.

first.py:

```
from second import Y
class X(object):

  def __init__(self):
   self.dict = dict()

  def test1(self):
   dict = {'a':'1','b':'2'}
   self.dict = dict
   return dict

  def action(self):
   performance = Y()
   performance.test2(**self.dict)
```

second.py:

```
class Y(object):
  def test2(self,**dict):
  return dict

if __name__ == '__main__'
  xinst = X()
  xinst.action()
  finaltest = Y()
  finaltest.test2()
```

I see the dict printing with correct information when printing in method `test2` (under class `Y`). But an empty dict (`{}`) is returned when I try to call it under `if __name__ == '__main__'`. Can anyone please help me/suggest me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `class Y(self):` would be a `NameError`

Comment: You're not passing any argument to test2 in the second file, hence the empty dict

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Got you..edited that !

Comment: But anyway, what did you expect? You defined `test2` to take an arbitrary amount of key-word arguments, `**dict`,  and simply return them. You then call the method without passing anything, therefore `dict` will be an empty `dict` (btw, **stop** using `dict` as a variable name, it shadows the built-in `dict`).  You then return that empty `dict`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Forget about the name of dict. Its not the exact name in my code. Ok, I get what you are saying. But what do I have to pass as an argument to test2 method? the same dict? Sorry for being dumb !

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Im just looking for a way to the use the dict in test2 method under "if __name__ == 'main' " block.

Comment: @chaitanya You just pass *arbitrary* keyword arguments: `finaltest.test2(a=1, x=4, anything_you_like=0)`

Comment: @AGNGazer Ok, I understand. As you can see in the above code, the dict in test2 method was passed through a method action in first.py file. I understand that we need to pass this way "finaltest.test2(**dict)". But before this I should be able to call that dict under "
if __name__ == '__main__'", then I can pass that dict to test2 method. This is looking kinda recursive, but thats what I am looking for. If there is a way to use the dict from test2 directly under if __name__ block, I'd love to hear it. IDK if thats possible. Thanks for your patience !

Comment: @chaitanya Sorry, but I do not understand exactly what are you asking... I just looked at your code and I fail to see what are you talking about when you say _"As you can see in the above code, the dict in test2 method was passed through a method action in first.py file"_ There are so many mistakes in your code that it cannot do anything of what you are imagining. For example, `performance = y()` would fail because `y`  is not defined. You probably meant `performance = Y()`. However, you cannot import `Y` because your import is wrong (in first.py): you are importing `test2` instead of `Y`!

Comment: ...(continued) That import in `first.py` would result in `ImportError: cannot import name test2` error. Finally, you did not mention that you are calling `Y.test2()` *through* the `X.action()` method in class `X`. You should describe your question better and more completely in order to get better answers. Yes, if all errors in your code are fixed, then indeed `X.action()` would pass a non-empty argument to `Y.test2()` which would have returned that `X.self.dict` object if you called `X.test1()` first (you never instantiated class `X` to create an object in your example) but you never print it.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include my attempt to fix your code

Comment: @AGNGazer I made the changes you're referring to. I honestly am clear till instantiating X in second.py (i.e. xinst.action()). By this action I can be able to print the right dict (not the empty dict) in test2. After this I am totally confused of how to use the dict that I am able to print correctly in test2 method under if __name__ block. I think my code needs to be restructured. Any ideas? Am I clear now?

Answer (score 1):

```
if __name__ == '__main__'
    finaltest = Y() # no arguments => dict = {} in Y.test2()
    finaltest.test2()
```

If you want `finaltest.test2()` to produce a non-empty dictionary, you will need to pass to it one or more *arbitrarily* named keyword arguments, e.g.,

```
finaltest.test2(a=1, x=4, anything_you_like=0)
```

Alternatively, it may be useful to do something like this:

```
myargs = {'a': 1, 'x': 4, 'anything_you_like': 0}
finaltest.test2(**myargs) # **myargs -> expand dictionary myargs
```

See https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/ for more information

Below I provide an attempt at fixing your code:

### first.py

```
from second import Y
class X(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.dict = dict()

    def test1(self):
        xdict = {'a':'1','b':'2'} # avoid overwritting built-in types such as 'dict'
        self.dict = xdict
        return xdict

    def action(self):
        performance = Y()
        return performance.test2(**self.dict)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = X()
    x.test1() # this sets the value of x.dict to {'a':'1','b':'2'}
    print(x.action())
```

### second.py

```
class Y(object):
    def test2(self,**ydict):
        return ydict

if __name__ == '__main__':
    finaltest = Y()
    print(finaltest.test2())
    print(finaltest.test2(A=1, B=2, C=3))
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case **name** would be 'second.py', or '**second.py**', as it is the module that you are referencing this through. Things get complicated when you have multiple files and try to use if **name** == '**main**': statements. I suggest trying another statement to reference the dictionary. Hope this helped.